# Yadcf filters in tfoot only work with th tag

Tags: datatables, yadcf

How can I apply filters in footer(tfoot) with this HTML ?

```
<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Filters are only applied when using `<th>` tag.

```
<tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I am using Yii2 GridView and footer there is generated with `<td>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution
*** Version:     0.8.8.beta.28**

Line 1909 and Line 1911 change `th:eq` to `td:eq`